# RequiredFieldValidator and RegularExpressionValidator for FreeTextBox show Error Message in 2 positions

Tags: c#, asp.net

In my aspx page:

```
<table cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2" align="center">
<tr>
  <asp:ValidationSummary ID="Alert" runat="server" CssClass="failureNotification" HeaderText=""/>                                  
</tr>

 <tr>
   <FTB:FreeTextBox id="FTB" runat="server"/>
  <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="FTB" CssClass="failureNotification" ErrorMessage="Content cannot be empty." ToolTip="Content cannot be empty." ></asp:RequiredFieldValidator> 
  <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="rev" runat="server" ControlToValidate="FTB" ErrorMessage="Text with only spaces is not allowed." ToolTip="Text with only spaces is not allowed "  ValidationExpression="[^\s]+" CssClass="failureNotification"/>                      
 </tr>
</table>
```

I'm using 1 `RequiredFieldValidator` and 1 `RegularExpressionValidator` for FreeTextBox `FTB`.

When I let the FreeTextBox empty, Error message of `RequiredFieldValidator` shows in 2 positions:[image]

And it is the same with Error message of `RegularExpressionValidator` when I press only space in FreeTextbox.

`Note:` 2 positions for `RequiredFieldValidator` and 2 positions for `RegularExpressionValidator`also. Not 2 position for both.

Help!!! I just only want the Error Message show in 1 position: in the top of table!!!